# I cannot Get the Background Color of my JPanel in main class

Tags: java, swing, awt

The Problem is I make a class that extends JPanel with gradient Color background but the problem is when I am getting the background of it to use it to other component is I cannot get the color of it. I want to set the background color of components same to other components

I had tried to use .getBackground(); But it doesn't work on it. what should I do so that I can get the background of it?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GradientPaintDemo extends JPanel {

private static final int scale = 2;
private static final Color c1 = Color.decode("#00F260");
private static final Color c2 = Color.decode("#0575E6");
private static final int size = (c2.getRed() - c1.getRed()) * scale;

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(size, size);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(20, 0, c1, 20, h, c2);
    g2d.setPaint(gp);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
}
```

then when in my Main Class

```
GradientPaintDemo gpd = new GradientPaintDemo();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

gpd.add(panel1);

panel.getBackground();
```

I want that to have only one background on all of my panels and buttons I want to look like this image below

[image]

Comment: At a guess, `panel1.setOpaque(false)` before adding it to `gpd`

Answer (score 1):

At a "guess" I would say you need to make the child component transparent, using `panel1.setOpaque(false)`, so the parent will show through it.

Also, at a "guess", the use of `size` in your `getPreferredSize` method could be causing you issues.  Instead, I'd set the component's default layout manager to `BorderLayout` and let the child dictate the required size.

For example, opaque...

[image: Opaque]

Transparent...

[image: Transparent]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() throws HeadlessException {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                GradientPaintDemo gpd = new GradientPaintDemo();
                gpd.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
                panel.add(new JLabel("This is a test"));
                panel.setOpaque(false);
                gpd.add(panel);

                frame.add(gpd);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class GradientPaintDemo extends JPanel {

        private static final int scale = 2;
        private static final Color c1 = Color.decode("#00F260");
        private static final Color c2 = Color.decode("#0575E6");
        private static final int size = (c2.getRed() - c1.getRed()) * scale;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(20, 0, c1, 20, h, c2);
            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you to you're answer I finally solve my problem ! :)